# override "/auth/identity"-page of omniauth identity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, omniauth

I'm using omniauth without devise for authentication, as I like it's simplicity. In addition to omniauth-facebook I use omniauth-identity to offer email/pw-authentication.
The [railscast on omniauth-identity](http://railscasts.com/episodes/304-omniauth-identity) describes how to setup a customized registration and login page. But the default routes supplied by identity (/auth/identity and /auth/identity/register) are still accessible.

I would like to have these under my control, as I want only want to let invited users register. Is there any way to override those routes supplied by a rack middleware?
Trying to just

```
match "/auth/identity", to: "somewhere#else"
```

doesn't do the trick!

Is there maybe a configuration to turn these default routes off? The documentation isn't giving any details on this...

Unfortunately I'm fairly new to Rack, so I don't have enough insight yet, to solve this issue on my own!
I'd be glad, if someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: In the end I just gave the invited users a passphrase, so it didn't really matter, that there was the original identity site still accessible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `OmniAuth` strategy object has a method `request_phase` which generates a html form and shows it to user. For "omniauth-identity" strategy this would be the form you see at `/auth/identity` url.

You can override the `request_phase` method and replace the form generator with, for example, a redirect to your custom login page (assuming you have it available at `/login` url). Place the following along with your omniauth initialization code:

```
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
   class Identity
     def request_phase
       redirect '/login'
     end
   end
 end
end

# Your OmniAuth::Builder configuration goes here...
```

Comment: If you want to override the request phase then you'll probably want to do the same with `registration_phase` too, and to make sure that the `registration_path` option is *not* set.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to 1gors and iains answer:

"/auth/identity/register" is served with GET as well, to override, I had to:

```
class OmniAuth::Strategies::Identity
  alias :original_other_phase :other_phase
  def other_phase
    if on_registration_path? && request.get?
      redirect '/sign_up'
    else
      original_other_phase
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: +1  I added this to `/config/initializers/omniauth.rb` under the `Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do  ...  end` block, together with @1gors answer.  Thanks  :o)

Answer (score 1):

You can set method in omniauth.rb

```
:on_login => SessionsController.action(:new)
```

for example:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity,
           :fields => [:nickname],
           :on_login => SessionsController.action(:new),
           :on_registration => UsersController.action(:new),
           :on_failed_registration => SessionsController.action(:registration_failure)
end
```